# DataGrid not binding (XAML + ViewModel + ObservableCollection)

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

New to the WPF + XAML + MVVM stack so I'm sure I'm doing something basic here, but Googling hasn't helped me figure it out. I think A second set of eyes may help.

## The Setup

- I have a list of Objects called FilesToAdd
- I have a DataGrid bound to this list
- I have a drag and drop event that fires handling code

  - I've confirmed this works via `Console.WriteLine()` output.

## The Goal

- When an item is added to the list, I'd like the datagrid to be updated with the appropriate information that has just been added to the list.

## The Problem

- The list seems to be updated, but the datagrid never is.

## The Code

Showing only the relevant parts.

### UploaderViewModel Class

```
private ObservableCollection<IAddableFile> _filesToAdd;
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       public UploaderViewModel()
       {
         _filesToAdd = new ObservableCollection<IAddableFile>();

        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }


        public ObservableCollection<IAddableFile> FilesToAdd 
        {
            get { return _filesToAdd; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _filesToAdd)
                {
                    _filesToAdd = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FilesToAdd");
                OnPropertyChanged("FilesAreQueued");
                }
            }
        }

        public bool FilesAreQueued
        {
            get { return (FilesToAdd.Count > 0); }
        }

        public void AFileHasBeenAdded(string filepath)
        {
                        var message = String.Format("File dropped: {0}", filepath);
                        Console.WriteLine(message);

            var newFileInfo = new FileInfo(filepath);
            if (newFileInfo.Exists && newFileInfo.Length > 0 && (!FileIsADirectory(newFileInfo))) // only add the file to the ViewModel if it's 
            {
                FilesToAdd.Add(new FileSystemFile(newFileInfo)); //Creating our own type becaause we do additional things with it
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("File added to list: {0}", newFileInfo.FullName));
            }
        }
```

### XAML Binding

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FilesToAdd}" Height="100" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="100" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Visibility="{Binding FilesAreQueued, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="File Name" Binding="{Binding FileName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size" Binding="{Binding FileSizeInText}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

What am I missing? I've been looking at the pattern and I know it has to be something simple I'm not seeing due to staring at a screen for too long. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** I suspect the `DataGrid` updates just fine but you can't see it because the `FilesAreQueued` property is lying.

You would need something like

```
FilesToAdd.CollectionChanged += (s,e) =>
    OnPropertyChanged("FilesAreQueued");
```

As you only want to do that once (if at all, can bind to `FilesToAdd.Count` directly), you really should opt for a `readonly` collection field.

---

Looks fine if the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) of the view is actually that view-model.

Another issue could be that the class is not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` (you can have the event without actually implementing it using `class : interface`), this would only apply if you overwrite the `FilesToAdd` property with a new instance. (In general i expose collections as `get`-only with a `readonly` field.)

Might want to check for [binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) (don't think you get any for bindings to a null `DataContext` though).

(Also i would recommend making the `OnPropertyChanged` thread-safe, i.e. `var handler = <event>; if (handler != null) handler();`)

Comment: OK, I added the handler code (thanks for the tip). I have no idea why the UI isn't updating though. Regarding the data context, I'm setting it as `DataContext="{StaticResource UploaderViewModel}"` and then in the window's constructor I'm creating an instance of the viewmodel class (so I can wire up dependencies) and then setting `Resources["UploaderViewModel"] = uploaderViewModel`. Everything else binds fine...

Comment: Yikes, sorry, I apologize, it seems that I overwrote your edits (i was editing at the same time to add more code; was trying a different route)

Comment: @SeanKilleen: No worries, was cosmetic anyway, but what you just tried is probably totally off :), you only need the event if the VM *itself* is bound as an `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Wait, so just to be clear, if I'm bound to an ObservableCollection, you're saying I don't even need to include the event handling?

Comment: @SeanKilleen: There are two mechanisms: property changing and collection changing, the former is only relevant if the instance assigned to a bound property changes, the latter only for instances already assigned as `ItemsSource`. In this case you do not need a setter for the collection property, the binding will get the instance once and update based on the instance's collection changed events. [ [e.g.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6028811/546730) ]

Comment: Reazlied your conclusion at the same time. I changed the datagrid to be always visible and you're right. However, this binding will eventually be two-way, so I think if I read your answer correctly it means I should add that additional listener to the event and that should handle it? (Thank you by the way).

Comment: @SeanKilleen: You need the listener, and that binding is never two-way. `ItemsSource` *cannot* propagate back to source, the `DataGrid` only ever modifies the collection itself not the bound property.